# tableView reloadData + Parse

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm trying to implement a refresh button in navigationBar, so when the button is clicked I need to reload the tableView, I have this code, but its not working, for sure the func is called because I put a println inside, Im also declare the reload on ViewDidAppear, but nothing happens :

```
import UIKit

class CommentsTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {
@IBOutlet var tabletView: UITableView!


var object : PFObject?

// Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

}

// Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "gameScore")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.whereKey("ObjectId", equalTo: "XDP1rc8Rmq")

    return query
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    // Refresh the table to ensure any data changes are displayed
    self.tabletView.reloadData()
    println("Reloading")
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


//override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CommentCellIdentifier") as! CommentsCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = CommentsCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CommentCellIdentifier")
    }


    if let object = object?["user"] as? String {
        cell?.username?.text = object
    }


    return cell

}

func buttonIconAction(sender:UIButton!)
    {
    println("Reloading")
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: How many results are being returned from the query (is the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method getting called)?

Comment: One result in this code, but I also tried returning more values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `tableView.reloadData()`, it looks like `PFQueryTableViewController` has a method called `loadObjects()`. Try calling that instead.